# SSL handshake failed when calling WebService

Tags: java, web-services, soap, https, oas

I'm having the error "javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Message send failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake failed" when calling a webservice from Java1.4 under https. The same call (same code) under http is not failling. Is there a problem with jdk1.4? I already imported the certificade with keytool

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Put the wsdl into a browser and it might give a clue about the cert error.

Comment: The browser doesn't have any problem retrieving the response. Firewall and SELinux are both disabled. Any other ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer. JDK1.4 doesn't recognize the algorithms in the domain ssl certificate (is not supported). I did upgrade to jdk1.6 and the error is gone.

[Here is some documentation about the Handshake error that is related to IOException](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/diagnosing-tls,-ssl,-and-https)